# In what scenarios are this two different ways of mapping import respectively suitable in Galaxybase?

Tags: graph-databases

In what scenarios are "front-end visualization interface mapping import" and "mapping import using import tool galaxybase-load" respectively suitable in Galaxybase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "front-end visualization interface mapping import" is a good option for simple graph models and small data sets. It lets new users of graph databases build graphs visually and easily. However, it uses the default configuration, so it's not suitable for importing large amounts of data.

The import tool galaxybase-load is designed for complex graph models and large data sets. With this tool, you can customize the mapping.json fields and optimize the hardware resources to improve the import performance. This method is suitable for advanced users.